# Low dimensional integral cohomology of $BPSO(4n)$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology, classifying-spaces

Toda has calculated the $\mathbb{Z}/2$‐cohomology ring of $BPSO(4n+2)$, and also gave the simple exceptional calculation of the $\mathbb{Z}/2$‐cohomology of $BPSO(4)$, in

- Hiroshi Toda, *Cohomology of Classifying Spaces*, Advanced Studies in Pure Mathematics 9, (1986) Homotopy Theory and Related Topics pp. 75-108, doi:[10.2969/aspm/00910075](https://doi.org/10.2969/aspm/00910075)

(This is also done in a different way in Kono–Mimura, referenced below, and by Baum–Browder) However for the general case of $BPSO(4n)$, we get a stability result for low-dimensional cohomology once $n\geq 2$, in particular $H^4(BPSO(8),\mathbb{Z}/2)$ gives all the higher-rank cases, too (this is in Kono and Mimura, *On the Cohomology of the Classifying Spaces of $PSU(4n+2)$ and $PO(4n+2)$*, doi:[10.2977/prims/1195191887](https://doi.org/10.2977/prims/1195191887)). Now I'm interested in the integral cohomology, rather than at the prime 2, mostly because amongst all compact simple Lie groups, $PSO(4n)$ is the only exceptional case where $H^3(PSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$ is **not** $\mathbb{Z}$, but is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$, assuming $n\geq 2$.

I presume the stability result still holds for integral cohomology (correct me if I'm wrong!), and so aside from the exceptional case of $BPSO(4)$, I presume that knowing $H^4(BPSO(8),\mathbb{Z})$ means we would then know all the groups $H^4(BPSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$.

Now I know that the torsion class in $H^3(PSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$ is even equivariant for the conjugation action of $PSO(4n)$ on itself, that is, it comes from equivariant cohomology $H^3_{PSO(4n)}(PSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$. But what I don't know is if this class comes from $H^4(BPSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$.

- What's a reference that gives the fourth integral cohomology group of $BPO(4n)$?

Comment: Although, if there is some well-known result like "$H^4(BPSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})\to H^4(BSpin(4n),\mathbb{Z})$ is injective, as is the case for all finite universal covers $\widetilde{G}\to G$", then I'll be feeling quite silly.

Comment: Arg, here I see that $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z})$ is always torsion-free for $G$ a compact connected Lie group: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180173/h4bg-mathbb-z-torsion-free-for-g-a-connected-lie-group. Further, André even shows in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02968 that $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z}) = H^4(BT,\mathbb{Z})^W$ for maximal torus $T$ and Weyl group $W$, so this is about as concrete as one could get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gawedzki and I have investigated this question for all compact simple Lie groups using the descent of multiplicative bundle gerbes from simply connected covers to quotients by subgroups of the center:

Gawedzki, Krzysztof, and Konrad Waldorf. "Polyakov-Wiegmann formula and multiplicative gerbes." Journal of High Energy Physics 2009.09 (2009): 073.
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2009/09/073/pdf

In your case, our results show that the pullback map
$$
H^4(BPSO(4n),Z) \to H^4(BSpin(4n),Z)=\mathbb{Z}
$$
is indeed injective, and that the image consists of all even $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $4$ divides $kn$.

EDIT: I extracted this from our paper as follows. $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z})$ classifies multiplicative bundle gerbes over $G$, and - that was our motivation there - Chern-Simons theories with gauge group $G$. In the paper we discuss the question when multiplicative bundle gerbes descent along the quotient map $\tilde G \to G:=\tilde G/Z$, where $\tilde G$ is a compact, connected, simply, simply-connected Lie group, and $Z$
is a subgroup of its center. For this purpose, we classified equivariant structures on multiplicative bundle gerbes over $\tilde G$, and obtained two results:

- Equivariant structures, if they exist, are in all cases unique. This shows injectivity of above map, or, in general, injectivity of the map
  $$H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^4(B\tilde G,\mathbb{Z}).$$
- The existence of equivariant structures is obstructed by the non-triviality of the so-called Felder-Gawedzki-Kupiainen-cocycle, which was known before for all $G$ and $Z$ as above. In the paper, we have a table on page 26 telling for all cases the obstructions ("called CS-constraints"), depending on $\tilde G$, $Z$, and the level $k\in \mathbb{Z}=H^4(B\tilde G,\mathbb{Z})$. In the relevant case of $\tilde G=Spin(4r)$ and $Z=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, this gives what I wrote above.

[image]

Comment: "Suggest"? That seems a little weak, if you'll pardon my bluntness; or do you have the proof?

Comment: Though, more seriously, thanks for that reference! It's something I will need to cite soon.

Comment: Well, we did not write this explicitly, and I was sort of digging it out from our results, that's why I wrote "suggest". I'll edit my answer and add an explanation how I did this.

Answer (score 1):

There is something special about $H^4$ that doesn't work in general. This way I can rely on a result proved by Henriques in

- *The classification of chiral WZW models by $H^4_+(BG,\mathbb{Z})$*, arXiv:[1602.02968](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02968), doi:[10.1090/conm/695](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/695)

and discussed at [$H^4(BG,\mathbb Z)$ torsion free for $G$ a connected Lie group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180173/h4bg-mathbb-z-torsion-free-for-g-a-connected-lie-group), rather than looking for a calculation of the cohomology of $BPSO(4n)$ in general. Namely that for **any** compact, connected Lie group $G$, $H^4(BG,\mathbb{Z}) = H^4(BT,\mathbb{Z})^W$, for $T\subset G$ a maximal torus and $W$ its Weyl group. Thus it is torsion free, and it's nothing to do with my special case. In particular the torsion class in $H^3(PSO(4n),\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't come from $BPSO(4n)$.